# the air in the forest was ... / the air was ... in the forest

Tags: word-order

> When the leaves were sprouting, **the air in the forest** was becoming really fresh.
>
> When the leaves were sprouting, **the air** was becoming really fresh **in the forest**.

Are both versions idiomatic and could be used in practice?

I'm sorry if some words aren't right for the context, for example, "fresh air", but I really tried to find the appropriate words for that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - (1) When the leaves were sprouting, **the air in the forest** was becoming really fresh.
> - (2) When the leaves were sprouting, **the air** was becoming really fresh **in the forest**.

Both (1) and (2) are grammatically valid, and each might well be said or written by a fluent speaker. Each would be understood by  a fluent speaker, and neither would be thought odd. The difference is one of emphasis, and style.

Sentence (1) emphasizes the word "*fresh*" and therefor the fresh quality of the air.  Sentence (2) emphasizes the word "*forest*" and thus the location. Which works better depends on the passage of which it is to form a part, but neither is poor writing.

The expression "*fresh air*" is natural and commonly occurs in use. Indeed it is something close to a fixed phrase.

Comment: Am I the only person who finds the combination of **leaves were sprouting** and **air was becoming** awkward.  Compare: **When I was running, my vest was becoming really wet.** Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Ronald Sole
 I might not write that, but I don't find either sentence at all odd as a reader. I think this is just a mater of style.

Comment: @David Siegel, If I understand right, in this phrase **"the air in the forest was becoming really fresh."** *"the air"* is at 1 place in its emphasis, *"really fresh"* is at 2 place in its emphasis, and *"in the forest"* is at 3 place in its emphasis. Is that right analysis?

Comment: @Sergei I don't understand what you mean by "1 place" "2 place" and "3 place" Those are not, terms that I have encountered previously. In general, the element mentioned **last** in an English sentence is most emphasized. The element mentioned **first** is also emphasized to a degree.  Tone of voice can also add emphasis, regardless of position.

Comment: @David Siegel, I thought that **first** word usually is most important in the sentence. But you say that it is **last** word. OK, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Sergei On further thought, I may have been too positive. But I think I can safely say that the first and least elements (and an element might be a noun phrase or a verb phrase, not just a single word) generally get more emphasis than those between.

Answer (score 2):

Either one *could* be used, but the word that comes last is going to command more attention. Which is more important to your point, that the air was fresh, or that the air was in the forest? Probably that it was fresh. Unless you are planning to write next about the air in another location, like the seacoast beyond the forest, your first formation is better. It may be better in either case.